# to store the output of the command "head" in a variable in expect

Tags: unix, expect

I have a huge file which has a version number of a particular bug.The version number is on the first line of the file so i use a "head filename" command.When I try to automate it using expect script,i.e.

```
set var [head filename.txt]
```

it throws an error saying invalid command name.When I try to do the other thing using expect_out,

```
send "head filename.txt\r"
expect -re {(n?)^V.*} {
set var $expect_out(0,string)
}
```

but this hasn't worked either.Can somebody help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
set var [exec head -1 filename.txt]
```

Alternatively, with no external programs needed:

```
set f [open filename.txt]
gets $f var
close $f
```

- you now have the first line of the file in $var.

Comment: It says couldnt open filename.txt:No such file or directory exists.I changed the file permissions too

Comment: Do you have the correct file name?  Is it actually called "filename.txt" ?
Is your script running in the same directory as this file?